# Adding a span tag to this menu in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am unable to add a span tag to the redmine project menu. You can see the full code at the redmine repository under trunk/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb around line 182. This is the line where I'm trying to add a span tag.

```
return content_tag('li', render_single_menu_node(node, caption, url, selected))
```

I tried adding a span tag like this:

```
return content_tag('li', render_single_menu_node(node, content_tag(:span, caption), url, selected))
```

but it renders the span tag as text in the browser like this:

<span>Overview</span>

The 'li' renders just fine. Is there a way to add the span tag correctly?

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
span_tag = content_tag(:span, caption).html_safe
return content_tag('li', render_single_menu_node(node, span_tag, url, selected))
```

By default, `content_tag` will escape any html content. You can use `html_safe` to prevent a string from being escaped.

On rails 2.3.x, there is no `html_safe` method, but you can pass an option to content_tag to tell it not to escape its contents:

```
span_tag = content_tag(:span, caption, {}, false)
return content_tag( 'li', 
                    render_single_menu_node(node, span_tag, url, selected), 
                    {}, 
                    false )
```

Comment: I just tried it, but now I'm getting this error: "undefined method `html_safe' for "<span>Sign in</span>":String". I don't know if this matters, but I am using rails 2.3.5.

Comment: From the looks of it, it doesn't look like html_safe is supported in rails 2.3.5. And redmine only supports version 2.3.5. Is there an alternative to html_safe or some other work around?

Comment: Please see updated answer for info on rails 2.3.x. (N.B. I added a comment last night with that info, but somehow it vanished!)

Comment: Hmmm....I see. I just tried your updated answer, but it still does the same thing for some reason. I restarted the server.

Comment: The first `content_tag` may need the escape options as well. See updated answer. If that doesn't work, the culprit is probably `render_single_menu_node`. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have an option to turn off escaping of html: http://rdoc.info/github/asoltys/redmine/master/Redmine/MenuManager/MenuHelper#render_single_menu_node-instance_method

Comment: Oh I see. It still does the same thing, so it didn't work. So like you said, render_single_menu_node is probably the culprit.